# Clarification on the wording of a Representation Theory problem in Dummit and Foote, 3rd Edition

Tags: representation-theory

I'm a bit confused by problem 21 in section 18.1 in Dummit and Foote, which says the following:

"Let $G$ be a noncyclic abelian group acting by conjugation on an elementary abelian $p$-group $V$, where $p$ is a prime not dividing the order of $G$.

a. Prove that if $W$ is an irreducible $\mathbb F_pG$-submodule of $V$ then there is some nonidentity element $g\in G$ such that $W\leq C_V(g)$ (here $C_V(G)$ is the subgroup of elements of $V$ that are fixed by $g$ under conjugation).

b. Prove that $V$ is generated by the subgroups $C_V(g)$ as $g$ runs over all nonidentity elements of $G$."

Now, the part I'm confused about is how one group, $G$, can act on a completely different group $V$ by conjugation, since $G$ acting on $V$ by conjugation would require $V$ to be a subgroup of $G$ for conjugation to be defined, and this is impossible since $p$ does not divide the order of $G$. I checked the errata and nothing about this problem is listed. Can someone help be understand what the intended meaning is?

Comment: It just means that $G$ is acting by group automorphisms, as opposed to just a set theoretic action that doesn't respect the additive structure of $V$.

Comment: So it's just a fancy way of saying that $G$ acts via the linear operators on $V=\mathbb F_p^n$ defined by its representation?

Comment: Yes. Conjugation refers to the concept of semi-direct products of groups.